# Slim. Не могу запустить "Hello World"

Tags: php, slim

Хочу изучить **Slim v4** для RESTFull сервера.

Открыл [Installation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/installation.html) на офф. сайте. Следовал строго по инструкции. На шаге **№3** выбрал **Slim PSR-7**.

При запуске приложения получаю следующую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found.
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:91
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(60):
>   Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
>   #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(64):
>   Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(174):
>   Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(158):
>   Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\index.php(16): Slim\App->run() #5 {main}
>   thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.com\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php
>   on line

Структура проекта:

```
test.com
--> vendor
--> .htaccess
--> composer.json
--> composer.lock
--> index.php
```

Содержимое **composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^4.0.0",
        "slim/psr7": "^0.4.0"
    }
```

Содержимое **index.php**

```
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
}
```

XAMPP v3.2.2

Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Запустил по иструкции на Open Server, путь к вендор только подправил. 
--> файл index.php лежит в корне папки/домена проекта - у меня slimpsr7
PHP 7.3.2 Apache2.4+nginx1.14

Структура:

```
slimpsr7
[vendor]
composer.json
composer.lock 
index.php //Именно тут hello
```

htaccess нет

При установке ошибок не было. После установки и перед запуском сервер перезагружен.

Содержимое composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "4.0.0",
        "slim/psr7": "^0.4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.6",
        "http-interop/http-factory-guzzle": "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^2.1"
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```